# How to interpret error received from request.get inside router.get as error in express.js?

Tags: node.js, express

**Design**

`R` as a back-end. I'm using [`plumber`](https://www.rplumber.io/articles/introduction.html) package to expose API.

`nodejs` and `expressjs` app. `express` checks the router and then requests appropriate API to get the data from R.

**code**

`R`:

```
#* @get /reportTypes
#* function to listen to the request and return the results from the csv file. 
#* If the file doesn't exists, it returns an 404 error.
#* @serializer unboxedJSON

function(res, req){
  
  filename <- "file-does-not-exist.csv"
  
  if(file.exists(filename)){
  
      reportTypes <- read.csv(filename)
   
      return(reportTypes) 
  }
  else{
    res$status <- 404
    stop("List of report types could not be loaded.")
  }
  
}
```

*Error from `R`*:

```
<simpleError in (function (res, req) {    filename <- "ReportTypes1.csv"    if (file.exists(filename)) {        reportTypes <- read.csv(filename)        return(reportTypes)    }    else {        stop("List of report types could not be loaded.")    }})(res = <environment>, req = <environment>): List of report types could not be loaded.>
```

`expressjs`:

Here, the router requests for the response from the given url. It does receive the error message from `plumber`, but I do not understand why the request then is passed to the client with a status 200 and the error is not interpreted by the client as an error. It instead interprets as a valid response.

```
router.get('/', function (req, res) {

  request.get({ url: 'http://localhost:5762/reportTypes' },
    function (error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        res.send(body);
      }
      else {
        console.log("Error: ", error);
        console.log("body: ", body);
        res.send(body);
      }
    });

});
```

What am I doing incorrectly that the error is not interpreted from `R` as error in `expressjs`?

Comment: you can refer this https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `res.send()` express will set the http-status code to `200` by default. You can change the code to something else using `res.status(<statusCode>)`. So, for example, if you want to send a `500` status, you can do:

```
 res.status(500).send(body);
```

Or you use the status-code from the backend-response:

```
 res.status(response.statusCode).send(body);
```

Note: The request-lib is deprecated though: https://github.com/request/request#deprecated so you might want to change to another lib.

Comment: That's good to know that `res.send()` sends 200 by default. Is there a way I can retrieve the error code from the `response` rather than setting it in express like you're suggesting? I can then handle all errors in `R`

Comment: Yes, there's a property `statusCode` on the respose-object, so you can do: `res.status(response.statusCode).send(body);` Please note that the request-lib is deprecated though: https://github.com/request/request#deprecated

Comment: oh! what can I use as an alternative to request? that's really helpful and important information you just gave.

Comment: We've recently switched to https://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/ and are happy with it. But there are many alternatives, axios for example.

Comment: I won't. It says 1 minute remaining :)